# Where do archaeological layers keep accumulating from?

Tags: archaeology

People always seem to be digging up stuff from below the ground - artifacts, buildings and entire cities. Often they are below a current city.

My question is - where do the layers covering the stuff keep coming from? Once upon a time the city was at the ground level and people were walling the streets, and now it is buried underground. Did the ground sink slowly? How did the old stuff get covered by new stuff? Where did the new stuff come from, considering it would take a lot of material to cover an entire city!

How come these ruins are never seem to be at the top? Has anyone done a study of this?

Comment: Ancient cities are usually located in flood plains that silt up. In other places, archaeological "layers" a really not seperated by much, or are confused.

Comment: Https://www.google.com/amp/ask.metafilter.com/237694/How-do-things-get-buried-in-dirt-over-thousands-of-years/amp. Also, http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/813/how-come-archaeological-ruins-are-always-underground/

Comment: Some ruins actually stay at ground level. See for instance the Colosseum in Rome, or some Roman aqueducts. For the rest, apart the flood plains point put forward by John, and exceptional scenarios like Pompeii, dust and vegetation (and trash) do their thing, little by little. See recent photos of Chernobyl to get a sense of how fast it can go.

Comment: For the same reason you have to vacuum or sweep out your living area every now and then. Archeology is what happens when nobody does that for a really long time.

Comment: They accumulate from sediment: dust in the air and stuff brought by water during the rain. Depending on the climate and geology, various places have various accumulation rates.

Comment: Wikipedia explains one way such things are formed - a 'tell' or mound formed by millenia of accumulated mud bricks & trash:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tell_(archaeology)

Comment: This happens even in [modern times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle_Underground)

Comment: This is actually an interesting question....but it can be easily answered by googling, and Spencer has given useful links which cover your question.